# JSF Bean attribute from other bean

Tags: jsf, static, set, javabeans

I try to bring the property of one ManagedBean (SessionScoped) (loginBean) to another (RequestScoped) ManagedBean (newsBean):

```
<c:set value="#{loginBean.user.nickname}" target="#{newsBean}" property="author" />
            <h3>News verfassen:</h3>
            <h:form>
                <p:inputText label="Titel" value="#{newsBean.title}"></p:inputText>
                <p:inputTextarea label="Inhalt" value="#{newsBean.description}"></p:inputTextarea>
                <p:commandLink type="button" value="Absenden" action="#{newsBean.writeMsg}"></p:commandLink>
            </h:form>
```

I thought that I can use the c:set tag like in the case I want to set a attribute "staticly".. :)

Maybe someone can help me?

Domii

----- AFTER ANSWER ------

LoginBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {
public LoginBean() {
    email = "";
    pwd = "";
    device = "";
    user = null;
}

private String email;
private String pwd;
private User user;
private String device;
/**
 * @return the user
 */
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

/**
 * @param user the user to set
 */
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

And NewsBean:

```
public class NewsBean {

@ManagedProperty("#{loginBean.user.nickname}")
private String nickname;

private String title;
private String description;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of NewsBean
 */
public NewsBean() {
}
```

And yes i also declare the getter /setter for nickname in user!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html).

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class NewsBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{loginBean.user.nickname}")
    private String author;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you - never heard about that :D

Comment: I have a problem with that:
ManagedBeanCreationException:

don't know why :/

Comment: Just read the root cause in the stacktrace of the exception to learn about the root cause of the exception? Perhaps you forgot the setter?

Comment: okey wait :P
I post ne whole declaration of the beans in my question ;)

Comment: I did it :) I hope you can see my failure :o

Comment: The setter should be in `NewsBean` as well, exactly as the exception message is trying to tell you. How else should JSF set it?

Comment: Problem:

In "newsbean" is the id (i don't need nickname now :]) 0 but in the loginBean it is 10 - i did the same as with nickname..
BTW no errors.. :/

Comment: would be nice if you have a look to my new problem :)

Comment: Apparently your `NewsBean` is not request or view scoped and/or you didn't send a redirect after login to force a new request/view being created which will create a fresh new `NewsBean` with the proper user ID. The `@ManagedProperty` is namely only set during bean's creation. If that's not an option for some strange design restrictions, then use `@ManagedProperty("#{loginBean}")` instead.

Comment: My NewsBean is a requestScoped and after the login there is a redirect.

But now i have the Problem everytime I log in and nav to the news page the old exception "ManagedBeanCreationException" appear...

put.. i have the setter.. i have everything like u said..

Comment: Just read the root cause in the stacktrace of the exception to learn about the root cause of the exception.

Comment: oke i don't know why.. but after i restartet netbeans it runs.. :o but with the value 0 instead of the right.. :)

Comment: I get this errorcode in my Glassfish server maybe that could be a reason?.. sry if not.. but i really have no idea o.o

PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /MineTime, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called

Comment: PWC4011 is unrelated and has already been asked (and answered) several times before here.